# Update a Spring object that have children without db id throws InvocationTargetException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I would like to know if it is possible to automatically update an spring object that have references to a list of children and some of children does not exist yet in Db, and needs to be inserted, not updated.

Suppose I have

```
 class User {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "_user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    SortedSet<Permission<?>> _userPermissions;
 }
 
 class Permission {
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
   private User _user;
 }
```

and suppose I retrieved from Db my user object, update it -

- Add new roles that does not exist in DB yet,
- Keep some that does exist, and
- Remove some others,

and I want to update my user in DB by

```
_userDao.save(userToBeInserted);
```

userToBeInserted hasDB id , it's old permissions does have db id, it's new does not have db id.

When I try to update that user I'm getting
`java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`
because some permissions are not in db yet.
If I would insert than in advance and copy the db it may work, But I 'm looking for a more cleaver solutions.
I also, would have to manually take care to remove permissions from Db that are not used and not assigned to user any more.

Basically, I want a clear spring configuration that automatically does the update/ delete/ insert for children for me.

Thank you

Comment: Please share entire Stacktrace of the exception that you are getting. It will be helpful in understanding the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In order to propagate the children changes to the database, you can configure `cascade` property of `@OneToMany` annotation.

In order to remove the children from the database that are no longer referenced by any parent, you can use `orphanRemoval` property on `@OneToMany` annotation.

So, in order to achieve your goals, try the following:

```
 class User {
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true, mappedBy = "_user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    SortedSet<Permission<?>> _userPermissions;
 }
 
 class Permission {
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
   private User _user;
 }
```

That way, when you call the `save()` on the parent, it will cascade the save operation to children as well.
`CascadeType.ALL` works for all types of operations, such as create, update, remove so it should address your use case.

You can learn more about cascading operations here https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-cascade-types

`orphanRemoval` property will clean up all the children entities that were removed from the parent so that they are no longer stored in the database.

In order to find out more about orhpanRemoval https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-cascade-remove-vs-orphanremoval

Comment: Thank a lot for your help @CaptainAye. Indeed it works, but is it also possible to remove children from db when they are missing in parent? Just wandering.

Comment: Yes, in order to remove the children in the database which are not connected to the parent anymore, you need to use orphanRemoval = true property. I updated the answer to reflect that question as well.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. Please remove double typed 'cascade = CascadeType.ALL' in the ocde, if you want